# Need JSR223 Pre Processor Groovy code to get code_challanges from Code verifier

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Need JSR223 Pre Processor Groovy code to get code_challanges from Code verifier using this

- code_challenge = BASE64URL-ENCODE(SHA256(ASCII(code_verifier)))

Can someone help here please

Answer (score 0):

If you decompose the task into pieces you will be able to find functions inside standard [Java SDK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) to implement the generation. Also there are ready solutions like [CodeVerifierUtil.java](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/blob/master/library/java/net/openid/appauth/CodeVerifierUtil.java)

Which can be adopted to your needs:

```
def code_verifier = 'foo'

//ASCII
def ascii = code_verifier.getBytes('US-ASCII')

//SHA256

def messageDigest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance('SHA-256')
messageDigest.update(ascii, 0, ascii.length)
def sha256 = messageDigest.digest()

//BASE64URL-ENCODE
def code_challenge = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(sha256)

log.info('Code challenge: ' + code_challenge)
```

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)